# How to see Kotlin stdlib source code in Intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin

Any idea how to obtain the source code for Kotlin's stdlib?

In the screencap below, I don't have any option to download the source code like other maven libraries.

I'm using the following Kotlin dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
    <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jdk8</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.30</version>
</dependency>
```

[image]

Comment: This is not the intended behavior, and I don't observe it on a small sample project. If you can reproduce it or provide details about the project setup (POM, layout), please report it to the [Kotlin issue tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/KT).

Comment: IDEA's Kotlin Plugin got updated and problem fixed. Thanks.

Comment: Not as convenient, but there is GitHub e.g.: https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/tree/1.3.20/libraries/stdlib/src/kotlin

Comment: @kuceraf - **2029**? :)

Answer (score 3):

For me it helps to change maven dependency on Kotlin in pom.xml from

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
    <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jdk8</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.30</version>
</dependency>
```

to

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.31</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

more info on adding Kotlin to project as maven dependency can be found here:
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-maven.html

Answer (score 0):

We can solve this by

1. import and attach source code or
2. using "idea" plugin in gradle build file.

=> *manually importing source code in intelliJ-idea*

Get source file from [github-release](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/releases)
I selected [1.6.21](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/archive/refs/tags/v1.6.21.zip) and added at following macos path(or find .m2 maven folder at respective OS)

```
/Users/${USER}/.m2/repository/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/<kotlin-version>
e.g.
/Users/${USER}/.m2/repository/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.6.21
```

When IDE prompts to download a source or attach a source, similar to following screen

[image]

Verify by checking the implementation of take for String class i.e. `"abcd".take(3)`.
when you go to take method's implementation before IDE decompiles String class and points to `StringsKt.java` but after source is attached it points to `_Strings.kt`
And it looks as

[image]

OR

=> You can add following code to `build.gradle.kts`, in latest kotlin version, source is getting downloaded along with versions so no manual effort.

```kotlin
// Add idea plugin
plugins {
    id("idea")
}
// configure idea plugin
idea {
    module {
        isDownloadJavadoc = true
        isDownloadSources = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Take in note of not all classes present in *...-source.jar* (e.g. missed `mutableSetOf()` in `Sets.Kt`)