# Kotlin Compile File Code is not Visible in Android Studio

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose

In my project I have used Kotlin Coroutines but issue is when I goto implementation of particular code than that is not visible.

Let me explain,

When I move to CoroutineScopeKt.class that is part of kotlin coroutines library it should be displayed source code but that is not visible.

Currently file looks like this.

[image]

It should be looks like below.

[image]

Comment: I have this problem too, but in IntelliJ IDEA (which is basically the same thing). It affects many people: see, for example, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49311545/how-to-see-kotlin-stdlib-source-code-in-intellij) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51766445/intelij-wont-show-sources-for-some-kotlin-classes). I suggest you [report it](https://developer.android.com/studio/report-bugs).

Comment: @k314159 I have facing issue in Android Studio. Don't know why ?

Comment: I think it's a bug in Android Studio.

Comment: @k314159 I have tried all approaches of above but bad luck none of them worked.

Comment: I don't think this problem is solvable, that's why I suggested you report it as a bug in Android Studio (or the Kotlin plugin to be precise).